# Is it possible to Move docker images from Public Docker hub to aws ecs?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, docker-registry, dockerhub

We are maintaining our docker images in https://hub.docker.com/ and now we want to move those images with all tagging version to aws ecs service. is it possible ? Do we have any  automatic scripts for the same ? Please help us on this.

Comment: Is [docker/migrator](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/migrator) of use for your case?

Answer (score 2):

You can pull images from **Docker Hub** from anywhere, given the right credentials are present (i.e. AWS is not any different from your local machine in this context).

If you want to keep the images "closer" to the Amazon environment, you could always publish them to [Amazon ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) instead and fetch them locally.

Bottom line is: **Amazon ECS** is a runtime environment for Docker containers, not a Docker Registry.

Comment: Suppose , If we want to move from Docker hub to ECR is possible ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj Yes, it's possible - once you have an ECR repository, you can simply `push` your Docker image there. You can also pull your images from Docker Hub directly. To sum this up: you need someplace to keep your images (e.g. Docker Hub or Amazon ECR) and something that will "run" those images (e.g. Amazon ECS). The latter doesn't care about the former in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can create ECR (not ECS) registries to host your images on AWS if you want to host your images on AWS instead of Docker hub.

To do this just run `docker push` to the ECR instead of to Docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tool which I created for my scenario to migrate the docker repository to AWS ECR.
https://github.com/amjad489/docker-pull-push